# Backups are crashing Computer or Filling Home Directory

Tags: backup, rsync

I am trying to setup a back up solution for my Linux computer: Ryzen 3950X, 64 Gb RAM, RTX 4070ti, 2Tb boot, 2 + 4 Tb internal drives.

- I tried "Backup" but it was filling up RAM (64 Gb), and the 32 Gb Swap file leading to a system crash.
- I tried "Back in Time", but the same thing was happening, and it used a lot of processing as well.
- I installed "luckyBackup" and that seemed better. However it created duplicate backups in my home folder and filled up the boot drive. However, it used negligible system resources (RAM/CPU).

Removing the unwanted data was tricky because I couldn't get into administrator mode to delete them, and I couldn't install the apt for running nautilus in admin mode because there was no room on the drive. I had some files on the boot volume that I could delete so I managed it in the end.

However, I am stuck. I don't know what backup solution to use that will reliably make a backup.

I have my home folder to backup, and 2 internal project drives. I have an 8 Tb backup drive to back them on to with about 6 Tbs of data to backup. I think the problem is the attempt to make "snapshots" which I just don't see the point of. I don't want snapshots, I just want a folder or a disk image of my data that is synchronised with the source.

Also, the directory to the drives goes through the computer which might be part of the problem. eg /media/carillon/Backup. I don't know. I can't see anywhere to stop luckyBackup saving duplicates to the home folder.

Edit - additional information. Somehow duplicates of one of the drives was also written to the other drive. This shouldn't have happened. The destination was the Backup drive only.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a more straightforward approach for your Linux desktop backup. Use Rsync for basic file copying. It simplifies the process, focusing on direct file copying without the complexities of full-featured backup tools. Set up a scheduled task, either through a cron job or systemd timer, for Rsync to run incrementally once a day. This ensures efficient copying of only changed files.

Exclude system and temporary folders from Rsync to avoid unnecessary data duplication and keep the backup streamlined. Utilize the Rsync archive flag to preserve essential file attributes like permissions, ownership, and timestamps during the copying process. Given potential changes in directory paths, consider using UUIDs or labels instead of static paths like /media for robustness.

Maintain a clear and organized structure on the backup drive by creating separate folders for each data drive. This avoids the intermingling of data.